How to access elements in popup using accesssibility service in Android
I've been working on an Accessibility Service to access an app's element data, such as text, description, resource ID, etc., using the following accessibility configuration:
<accessibility-service
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewLongClicked|typeViewScrolled"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

With this setup, I'm able to capture events when interacting with elements in the app. However, when a popup opens, and I try to interact with buttons (e.g., a search button, star message, reply button) within the popup, no events are triggered in the onAccessibilityEvent() function. (The popup is shown in the attached screenshot).

I also tried modifying the configuration by changing the android:accessibilityFlags to:
android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestTouchExplorationMode|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagReportViewIds"
However, I still only receive the root element of the screen. I know this functionality is possible since services like TalkBack can handle such interactions effortlessly. What might I be missing to achieve the desired functionality?
Code for bottomSheet:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <!--image view for displaying course image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <!--text view for displaying course name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVCourseName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:text="DSA Self Paced Course"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!--text view for displaying course tracks-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVCourseTracks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idTVCourseName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:text="Course Tracks : 30"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <!--text view for displaying course duration-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVCourseDuration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idTVCourseTracks"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:text="Course Duration : 4 Months"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <!--button for dismissing our dialog-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/idBtnDismiss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Dismiss dialog"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

code to open bottomsheet from activity:
val openBottomSheetButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.open_bottom_sheet_button)
        
        openBottomSheetButton.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
            
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet, null)
            
            val btnClose = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnDismiss)
            
            btnClose.setOnClickListener {

                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            dialog.setCancelable(false)

            dialog.setContentView(view)
            
            dialog.show()
        }


Hi there! Could you either tell us how the bottom sheet was implemented, or give an example app? What complicates Ally services like this is that there are 2 apps involved (The Ally service [A] and the target application [B]) . If there is an example app / code for the app ([B]), it'll be better for folks to answer, because they won't make assumptions about [B], and can focus on the problem [A].

Hi, thanks for your input! I've updated the question with the XML code for the BottomSheet and its items. Could you take a look now? Interestingly, accessibility features like TalkBack work well on the same BottomSheet where my Accessibility Service isn't able to capture any events. Is it possible to find out what configuration or features TalkBack is using that I'm missing in my service?

I'll take a look soon, but in the meantime yes you absolutely can see how TalkBack is implemented, and the service config

Sure,I really appreciate your input. I also added the code for calling bottom-sheet from the activity, and I've tried it with the talkback accessibility service configuration as well. While I'm able to capture the root element of the BottomSheet when it opens, I'm still not receiving any events for the individual elements inside while clicking. I'm only looking to capture the source of the element the user clicks, rather than listening to all events like TalkBack does. Any further guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I think this question also raises the same issue

Edit
I then went back and reviewed the question, the most important section:

I try to interact with buttons (e.g., a search button, star message, reply button) within the popup ... no events are triggered in the onAccessibilityEvent() function

My answer demonstrates we can definitely interact with the popup buttons, but it does not address the event registry once the popup is opened, for example TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED
I did check and we are able to retrieve all the content on WINDOW_STATE_CHANGE:
    private fun AccessibilityNodeInfo.forAllChildren(depth:Int = 0, fn:(AccessibilityNodeInfo, Int) -> Unit) {
        for (index in 0..<this.childCount){
            this.getChild(index)?.let {
                fn(it, depth)
                it.forAllChildren(depth+1, fn)
            }
        }
    }

    // inside onAccessibilityEvent
    if (event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        rootInActiveWindow.forAllChildren { node, depth ->
            Log("${" ".repeat(depth * 2)} ${node.viewIdResourceName} ${node.text}")
        }
    }


However we cannot see once the view is clicked:
    // inside onAccessibilityEvent
    if (event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {
        Log("onAccessibilityEvent CLICKED ${event.className ?: " "}")
    }

I will spend some more time on this later, but this is a problem, and it's possible we need to raise a bug on the issue tracker
Original Answer
I had some time to look into this a little more and to be honest I'm still a little confused, but I have managed to create a small demo. I still don't know the actual point of why we're trying to do this.
My current questions related to this question:

How does this help people with disabilities?
Is this used in conjunction with assistive technologies (e.g. Talkback, Voice access, etc)?

But instead of sitting on questions, I thought I'd give it a go with the information I have. Now here is what I did:

Write a custom views app that opens a bottom sheet, using as much of your code as possible
Write custom accessibility service that tracks user movement and if the bottom sheet is shown, see if I can find the dismiss button and click it

accessibility_service_config.xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagReportViewIds"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    />

SampleAccessibilityService.kt
class SampleAccessibilityService: AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onInterrupt() {
        Log("onInterrupt")
    }
    
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        Log("---------------------------------------------------------")
        Log("onAccessibilityEvent CLASS ${event?.className ?: " "} -- ${BottomSheetDialog::class.java.name}")
        Log("onAccessibilityEvent EVENT ${event?.eventType ?: " "}")
        Log("onAccessibilityEvent TEXT  ${event?.text ?: " "}")

        if (event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && event.className == BottomSheetDialog::class.java.name) {
            rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Dismiss dialog").forEach { node ->
                Log("    onAccessibilityEvent CLICKING A NODE")
                node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        Log("onServiceConnected")
        serviceInfo.apply {
            // I have found you have to do this in the config and onServiceConnected. Mine are actually mismatched but the service worked fine. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED or AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED
            notificationTimeout = 100
        }
    }
}

object Log {
    operator fun invoke(text: String) {
        android.util.Log.d("SAMPLEALLYSERVICE","SAMPLEALLYSERVICE: $text")
    }
}

When I enable this service from the Settings menu:

Settings -> Accessibility -> Sample Accessibility Service -> Use Sample Accessibility Service
Open my test application
Open the bottom sheet

I am able to see that it is immediately closed.

In summary, you have to use event triggers in the accessibility service to know that certain aspects have change, like the TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED - I then looked for the nodes by text rather than by ID because ID's are going to become a lot less prevalent (Jetpack Compose) and I can send an interaction command through the accessibility node:
node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)

Hi, thanks for your response! I’m facing a similar issue where Jetpack Compose elements aren’t triggering any accessibility events, as someone pointed out in this Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1euf09x/why_accessibilityservice_is_not_working_compose/
I’d be happy to open a separate question and provide more details, including code snippets, if you need any additional resources.
